# Inflating multiple layouts in a fragment causes main drawyerlayout activity slower.help needed

Tags: android, fragment, drawerlayout

I have a main Activity DrawerActivity containes xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#333"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment class loaded from my DrawerActivity.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.welcome_activity, container, false);

    initTabber();

    return rootView;
}
private void initTabber() {


        tabbar = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabbar);
        tabLayout = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.tabbar_layout, null);
        tabbar.addView(tabLayout);
        tabbarManager = new TabbarManager(context, tabLayout, activity);
        tabbarManager.initTabbar(false, false, false, false);
        ViewGroup tabGroup = (ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabberContainer);
        FontsHandler.ApplyFontToGroup(tabGroup, AppConstants.EXT_MEDIUM);
}
```

When i inflate tabber layout in initTabber methods my DrawerActivity gets slower. I mean DrawerLayout menu is not opening smoothly.Help need pls

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry i could't post a image bcz of less reputation points. I am trying to use Drawerlyaout slider menu top of my fragment which loads multiple layouts dynamically.

Comment: sure you not blocking the UI thread ?